# Cheap Android 7' tablet (800x480): wrong aspect ratio, circles look like ellipsis

Tags: android, geometry, aspect-ratio, ellipsis

I need a lot of Android tablets for resale with my app. I bought some from internet (cheap chinese products) but all 7' 800x480 tablets shows circles as ellipsis (squares as rectangles), everything is stretched...

Some are Android 2.3.3, others are Android 4.0 but all of them show stretched UI.

Did someone have encountered the same problem?

Comment: Only with your app or also in System apps?

Comment: All Android Ui looks stretched, not only my app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some flashing some new builds with changes in the `sysconfig1.lhs`, I've come to the conclusion that I don't believe there's a solution. The tests I did were on a Allwinner A10 tablet, specifically the M703 model running Android 4.0.4. Note that there are many devices with the same (or similar) hardware configuration but different names.

I dived into the `sysconfig1.lhs` that's included in the system image, which contains these lines:

```
lcd_x = 800
lcd_y = 480
```

And the corresponding touch screen values:

```
ctp_screen_max_x = 800
ctp_screen_max_y = 480
```

I measured the screen, which appears to be identical to Seraphim's measurement: 155×86mm. Working with that, I experimented with changing those values to either 864×480, or 800×444.

Unfortunately, neither option solved the issue.

864×480 simply clipped 64 pixels part of the display.

[image: Photo of 864×480]
[image: Screencap of 864×480]

800×444 crashed SystemUI (as it no longer qualifies as `sw480dp` and therefore expected the device to be phone) and left a 36 pixel gap.

[image: Photo of 800×444]
[image: Screencap of 800×444]

Perhaps the screen resolution needs to be set somewhere else, but I believe that it's the hardware that's somehow misconfigured.

There are many other lines in `sysconfig1.lhs` that are meaningless to me, such as:

```
lcd_dclk_freq            = 33
lcd_if                   = 0
lcd_hbp                  = 46
lcd_ht                   = 1055
lcd_vbp                  = 23
lcd_vt                   = 1050
```

Perhaps there's some way of changing the pixel ratio, but I haven't experimented.

Comment: Seems to be a common issue for Allwinner A10 M703  coming from China... I tryed several cheap tablet and all of them have a wrong aspect ratio. Anyway, thank you for your post.

Answer (score 2):

They are probably either:

1. not matching the screen physical size with the resolution aspect ratio. What is the physical size (width and height) of the screen?
2. having non-square physical pixels

If either of that is the case there is not much you can do unless you can do some serious hacking and change the resolution. You get what you pay for I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi Pulsar, thanks for the comment. I think the problem is on the pixel aspect ratio. And I also think that the most cheap products from China uses low cost display that are not suitable for a good looking display. Anyway, the DisplayMetrics is { density=1.0, width=480, height=800, scaleDensity=1.0,m xdpi=160.0, ydpi=160.42105}.

Comment: OK, how does that match the physical size of the display? Use a ruler or something. :)

Comment: OK so a 16:9 physical aspect ratio of the screen. If the pixels are squares the resolution of the screen could actually be correct but not set correctly. Depends on the panel and graphics chip used if it supports those resolutions. If the resolution had been Full WVGA 854x480 (16:9) it would match the physical display. 800x480 is 5:3 (WVGA).

Comment: So I think there is no software solution for that, except coding all ui components and adjust scale before drawing on the canvas...

Comment: The manufacturer or if you use a custom ROM could compensate for that in the display metrics I guess.

Comment: @Mattias I've gotten a hold of the ROM and can flash it onto the device. Can you give a little insight into how the display metrics are specified? The `sysconfig1.lhs` file in the build contains those measurements for `ctp_screen_max_x` and `ctp_screen_max_y`, but changing them only offsets touch events ("ctp" appears to abbreviate "capacitor touch panel").

Comment: @Mattias I did a few tests and followed up with an answer.